# Dois Layouts.xml para um mesmo Fragment, é possível?

Tags: android, android-layout

A minha dúvida é a seguinte:

- É possível usar dois layouts num mesmo Fragment?

O contexto da minha dúvida, é o seguinte: eu queria um formulário, onde o utilizador introduzisse várias informações, só que não consigo colocar tudo no mesmo layout, e pensei no exemplo da configuração inicial do android:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria uma funcionalidade deste genéro onde o utilizador, preenchesse um formulário em vários passos. Para se desenvolver, há alguma maneira de usar vários layouts  no mesmo fragment ou para cada passo da configuração é necessário o uso de vários fragments e respectivos layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa é você usar o `include` para incluir um outro *layout* no seu `FrameLayout`. A lógica é o seguinte, você deixa um *layout* escondido e o outro a vista. Desta form, no momento em que você clicar no botão <kbd>Próximo</kbd>, você oculta o *layout* que está a vista e mostra o *layout* que está escondido. Veja:

**XML**

```
<FrameLayout ...>
    <include 
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        layout="@layout/linear1"/>
    <include 
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        layout="@layout/linear2"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Fragment**

```
View layout1, layout2;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
    layout1 = root.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    layout2 = root.findViewById(R.id.layout2);

    return root;
}
// aqui seria seu botão, que escondera seu layout1 e mostrará o 2.
public void mostrarLayout2() {
    layout1.setVisibility(GONE);
    layout2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
}
```

Essa seria praticamente uma base, dependendo do que você for fazer, dá para adaptar muito bem.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Vou experimentar a resposta! :)

Answer (score 3):

Uma possibilidade é usar ViewStub.
[ViewStub](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) é uma *view* leve sem dimensões que não participa no *layout*.

Crie um *layout* por cada parte do formulário.

No layout da Activity/fragment onde quer apresentar o formulário declare uma ViewStub por cada parte:

```
<FrameLayout ...>
    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/stub_parte1"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/frm_parte1"
        android:layout="@layout/formulario_parte1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/stub_parte2"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/frm_parte2"
        android:layout="@layout/formulario_parte2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    ...
    ...
</FrameLayout>
```

Para obter uma referência a cada ViewStub use:

```
stub_parteX = ((ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub_parteX));
```

Para trazer para a tela cada uma das partes do formulário use:

```
View formulario_parteX = stub_parteX.inflate();
```

Para esconder um parte use:

```
stub_parteX.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

A vantagem do uso de ViewStub, sobre o tradicional *hide/show* de *layouts*, é a ViewStub manter a hierarquia de *views* mais leve, já que os *layouts* só são adicionados à hierarquia depois de "inflados".

Comment: obrigado, pela resposta, estou a testar várias possibilidades,e entretanto ocorreu-me um pequeno erro que estou a tentar resolver, mas logo que possa, vejo a sua solução :)